# Displaying donation list (showing appreciation for people who donated)

Tags: community

Me and my girlfriend thought about making a kind of "activistic" website, a platform that tries to improve life of regular people and improve services being provided by various kind of businesses.

We want to add an ability for people to donate to us. We are completely non-profit driven but any help to support the platform would let us focus more at what we are doing.

As I would like to keep everything as "transparent" as possible. First I thought about listing on separate page all people who donated: names and donated amount, but after thinking more I realized it would make a person who donated let's say 10€ to look "better" than a person who donated 1€.

So I want to ask which would be the most direct way to display donations and show appreciation to people who donated, while not causing to some differents kind of uncomfortable feelings and also not dragging their attention away from the whole activity of the community.

**Updated**:
Exactly as #Crissov said. As for some people 5€ might mean as much as for other people 100€. I wouldn't want to give to someone more importance than to other just of bigger donation. What I want to encourage is basically helping each other out and making you feel good as you decided to be a part of the project.

Comment: Listing donators by absolute amount would be putting them in the order of worth to *you*. For some people, 10 € is worth less than 1 € is for other people. Since you cannot know this relative worth of a donation, do not show the absolute amount at all and find a different property to sort by. My suggestion would be chronological order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using this as an opportunity to dialogue with your contributors:  i.e. Do they WANT to be publicly acknowledged?  "You're one of our strongest supporters... Can we spotlight you?"

Another standard *distancing* technique might be to identify different "classes" (i.e. donation thresholds) and then acknowledge individuals that way

or simply provide raw aggregate numbers, without the overhead of naming individuals (i.e. "more than a million individual donations - an average of $27 apiece")